# Apple Code Redemption - presentCodeRedemptionSheet() doesn't give any feedback

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

We have implemented the redemption of offer codes using the function

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().presentCodeRedemptionSheet()
```

the modal appears correctly and the flow ends successfully, we receive the callback from apple on the server side, the problem is that we do not receive feedback on the app side and we cannot guarantee a good user experience. in particular it seems that the function

```
paymentQueue (_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])
```

is not called, but we are not sure because we can't find a way to test it.

The standard app purchase flow works fine, but code redemption does not.

In general it is very difficult to test these discount codes because they are only testable with the app in production, without being able to take advantage of the debug prints or breakpoints. In addition, a particular offer can only be redeemed once per apple id

Is there any way to test offer codes in debug mode?

How could we do some tests on the code without sending the app for verification every time?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm running into the same issues.

Comment: Any update on this? Facing the same issue in iOS 15 I can see a success message and after that sheet dismissing but the payment queue does not receive anything. If the user restarts the app, user gets access like after purchase. @Jared

Comment: Hi this is not been updated for a while, did you ever found a solution for this?

Comment: Hi, same here. did you find any solution?

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this? I'm in the same boat as you.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Have any updates been found?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my workflow based on my assumption, and it worked well when I first wrote this answer.

[image]

Sadly, as @mota mentioned, in this situation, in iOS 15.4 `willResignActiveNotification` followed by `didBecomeActiveNotification` immediately, which broke my assumption.

---

When StoreKit presents the CodeRedemptionSheet, UIKit will call `applicationWillResignActive`.

And when I click the cancel button or swipe it off, UIKit will call `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Maybe you can use this feature to catch its status.

Comment: The Problem with this solution is, that on each of those events you fire the call to StoreKit, which is a massive overhead of requests.

Comment: When you call the redemption sheet on 15.4 you get a notification for `willResignActiveNotification` followed by `didBecomeActiveNotification` immediately. This API is so unreliable unfortunately :(

Comment: what is this redemptionStatus? is this something you wrote just for explaining yourself the flow? I didn't see any such enum of the documentation.

Comment: Thank you ahi and @mota - the didBecomeActiveNotification helped me pop a "thank you for your purchase" alert in this scenario. I (1) set a flag when the Redeem Code button is pressed (2) checked didBecomeActive and if flag is set the (3) check the entitlements and if they now have a purchase then thank them / state transition / etc